# How to change the FROM address in mail

Tags: linux

How to change the `mail` FROM address in Red Hat Linux 6? I send a mail by using this script:

```
TO_ADDRESS="myfriendaddress@gmail.com"
FROM_ADDRESS="myaddress@gmail.com"
SUBJECT="SERVER FAILURE"
BODY="SERVER IS FAILED NOW"

echo ${BODY}| mail -s ${SUBJECT} ${TO_ADDRESS} -- -r ${FROM_ADDRESS}
```

But the email address in the FROM field is always `root@redhat.localdomain`
How to change the FROM address to something like `myaddress@gmail.com`

Comment: Try moving the `-r ...` to just after `mail`. Also, it depends on which mail client you are using. What does `rpm -qf /usr/bin/mail` say?

Comment: If you don't want `mail` to stop processing options, then don't put `--` before `-r`.  Also, you **really should** double-quote your variables, even if they are in curly-braces - curly braces are not a substitute for proper variable quoting, they are for disambiguating a var from surrounding text (e.g. `${foo}123` means the contents of `$foo` followed by `123` while `$foo123` means the contents of variable `$foo123`).  `"${SUBJECT}" and "${BODY}" especially need it as they contain unescaped space characters.   but double-quote ALL of them, not just $SUBJECT and $BODY.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify any extra header you may need with `-a`

```
$echo "This is the main body of the mail" | mail -s "Some random subject" -a "From: some@domain.com" to@domain.com
```

**Alternative Solution**

In my version of mail, the following options work for controlling the source / reply addresses

- the `-a` switch, for additional headers to apply, supplying a From: header on the command line that will be appended to the outgoing mail header
- the `$REPLYTO` environment variable specifies a Reply-To: header

so the following sequence

```
export REPLYTO=to@example.com
mail -aFrom:from@example.com -s 'Testing'
```

The result, in my mail clients, is a mail from `from@example.com`, which any replies to will default to `to@example.com`

*NOTE by @Rui F Ribeiro: only the root user is able to change the From field.*

Comment: +1 for the post. I also suggest you adding to your answer that with this method, only the root user is able to change the From field. Mainly because developers often have a hard time understanding why with sendmail compatible APIs they are not able to change the From address, and while talking via a TCP based API/function, they can change it at will.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Thanks for your suggestion. Updated the answer. You can update my answer for more details if you want.